# Retrieve Barcode Images one by one from PDF

Tags: java

I have created one pdf in which there is list of barcode images.I have to select one by one barcode image from it and have to send it to printer.So that I can take print out of each barcode image and use it as a sticker.How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).